# What was the green drink that Scotty could not identify?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In the *Star Trek: TOS* episode "By Any Other Name", Scotty gets alien captor Tomar drunk.  Tomar asks him about one particular bottle:

> TOMAR: "What is it?"
>
> SCOTTY: "Well, it's… uh…"  (Scotty looks at the liquor bottle and sniffs it)  "It's green."

**What is the green drink in that particular bottle?**  Films, scripts, novelizations, and licensed works are acceptable sources.

No, I do *not* want the identity of the [similar scene in TNG: Relics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160570/102339), which is identified by Picard as Aldebaran whiskey.  That is a *different bottle*.  And don't speculate that they're the same -- sources, please.

Comment: Given the humor of that line, I think it's very unlikely that any information on the drink exists beyond what's established in that scene: 1. It's alcoholic 2. Scotty found it on Ganymede 3. It's green.

Comment: Maybe it's cold medicine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All signs point to it being [Aldebran Whisky](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Aldebaran_whiskey). The official (Blish) adaptation has a slightly different version of the scene, presumably based on an earlier version of the script.

> Finally, however, they were seated at Scott’s desk with a bottle and
> glasses between them. After a while, it was two bottles. Tomar seemed
> to remain in total control of himself, as if he’d been drinking
> lemon-ade. “No more?” he said.
>
> “Well… no more Saurian brandy, but…” Scott looked around and found
> another bottle. **“Now, y’see, this liquor is famous on Ahbloron-I mean,
> Aldibib-ble-on one of these planets we go to.”**
>
> “It is a different color from the other.”
>
> “Yes. And stronger, too.” He poured some into To-mar’s glass with an
> unsteady hand, and then, per-force, some into his own. Somehow this
> experiment was not working out right.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek 6: By Any Other Name](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_6)</sup></sub>